# Variable declaration in make tools

Tags: linux, makefile, environment-variables

Let we have a simple `make-file`:

```
default:
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c

CC=gcc
FLAG= -o
TARGET=binary
```

So does variables `CC`, `FLAG` and `TARGET` will be added to environment variables array of `make` tool or this variables doesn't depend of `make`'s variable environment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're asking here, but: make maintains its own set of variables which are entirely separate from "environment variables" (in the standard system definition of environment variables).  When make expands a variable (such as `$(CC)`), it uses the value in its set of "make variables", not "environment variables".

When make starts up, it imports all its environment variables as "make variables" so they can be accessed via normal make variable expansion.

If you change the value of a make variable which is also part of the environment, then the value in the environment is also changed.  Also when you use the `export` keyword (in GNU make) then make will put that variable in the environment as well.

When make runs a program it passes the environment variables, but not the make variables, to the program it's running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if we added to `default` target's recipes an `env` recipe we have that the array of environment variable will be displayed. Is it true that it will be the shell's variables, not `make` tool variables, because recipes executed in the shell itself?

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand your questions so pardon me if I don't get it right, but when I say "runs a program" above, that means any command in a recipe that make invokes in any way, for any target.  If that recipe contains the `env` program, then the environment shown will be the environment that the program was started with, which is the environment that make passed to it.  That will _NOT_ include all the make variables.  It will only include the variables that were in the environment that make was started with, plus any variables specified by the make `export` command.

Comment: Does a specific recipes are executed in `make` processes or `bash` processes is invoked before the recipe is executed?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand that well enough to try to answer it.