# make command execution from the Makefile

Tags: makefile

Consider the following `Makefile`:

```
CURRENT = $(shell uname -r) 
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build 
PWD = $(shell pwd) 
TARGET1 = md1 
TARGET2 = md2 
TARGET3 = md3 
obj-m   := $(TARGET1).o $(TARGET2).o $(TARGET3).o 
default: 
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

Is it true that the variables which declared in the current `Makefile` is coming to the `$(KDIR)/Makefile`.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question a few days ago, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941380/variable-declaration-in-make-tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.  In general make variables are internal to make, and are not available in recursive invocations of make.

If you want the variable to be available in the sub-make, you need to either pass it on the command line for the sub-make, or else `export` it from the parent make; the latter will put it in the environment when the sub-make is invoked.

Note, though, that assignments in makefiles override values taken from the environment.  So the `$(KDIR)/Makefile` will need to be careful to test the value before setting it, if it does.

By the way, you should never invoke a recursive make with the literal `make`.  *Always* use the variable `$(MAKE)`.

Comment: _Always use the variable $(MAKE)._ Why `MAKE` variable must be used rather than make literal?